# How to move a SQL Server LocalDB database to a new computer

Tags: c#, sql-server, localdb

I purchased a new computer. On my old computer I had created an ASP.NET Core 1.0 web application project that uses Entity Framework Core. I now need instructions for how to move the project & database to my new computer for further development. I have copied all of the Visual Studio solution's files to a folder on the new computer. When I try to run it I get a database login failure exception.

I located the database on the old computer in the `C:\Users\steven\` folder as `aspnet-Intake-c7c5<more numbers>.mdf` (and another one with .ldf). Also on the old computer the database also shows up in Visual Studio's SQL Server Object Explorer under `(localdb)\MSQLLocalDB\databases\`. I copied the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files to the `C:\Users\steve\` folder on the new computer (note the username change from steven to steve) but it does not show up in the SQL Server Object Explorer on the new computer.

Can anyone tell me how to get the copied database into the SQL Server Object Explorer on the new computer so my application can hopefully locate it? I am using Windows 10. Old computer has Visual Studio 2015 and new computer has Visual Studio 2017.

Thank you all for your answers.  As it turns out, I had used Entity Framework so I was able to use EF Database Migrations to recreate the DB.  If it will help anyone else, if you used ef database migrations and want to re-create the DB you just go into the Nuget Package Manager Console and use the command update-database.  It recreates the database (but, of course, not the data).  I was not concerned about the data since it's just data used for development and testing.  I will try to phrase my questions better in the future. Thanks again.  It's working now.

Comment: If you open up the project on Visual Studio and double-click on the database file, it should open the database on the SQL Server Object Explorer window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I move a SQL Server LocalDb database from one machine to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371902/how-can-i-move-a-sql-server-localdb-database-from-one-machine-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

you can use from Attach and detach in MSSQL

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-a-database-using-detach-and-attach-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Or

you can use from backup and restore in MSSQL

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/create-a-full-database-backup-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-a-database-backup-using-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: OP is asking about an MSSQL LocalDB instance.  That is not the same as an MSSQL DB, and there is no backup function.  A MSSQL LocalDB is for development only and only runs when a user is connected to it.